# Combining multiple queries to be displayed in one table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to calculate the Monthly Active Users. The system matches users with freelances who complete certain tasks. I have 3 tables, one is the users table, one is the task request table, and one is the task match table. The types of users are: available users who simply signed in to the app, active users who made at least one task request, and engaged users who made task requests and completed them as well.
My first query to get the available users is like so:

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM users 
WHERE users.created_at >= '2021-01-01' AND users.deleted_at is not null
```

My second query which is to get the active users:

```
SELECT count(distinct user_id) as active_users 
FROM tasks_requests 
WHERE tasks_requests.created_at >= '2021-01-01')
```

My third and last query is to get the engaged users:

```
SELECT count(distinct task_request_id) as engaged_users 
FROM task_matches 
WHERE task_matches.created_at >= '2021-01-01' AND task_matches.state = "completed"
```

My desired output is to get a table that shows the number of each type of users for each month:

| date | available_users | active_users | engaged_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2021 | 200 | 150 | 75 |
| Feb 2021 | 145 | 63 | 52 |
| Mar 2021 | 215 | 125 | 95 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: It looks like you just need to join your queries together by date. Can you update your code to include a date or month/year field?